# Find next row class after specific row class in each table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need to hide unused toggle buttons with jQuery.
e.g. show toggle buttons only if after header `<tr class="header">` next is data `<tr class="data">` 
I have dynamic populated table that is as the code below:

```
 <table>
  <tr class="header">
    <td><a class="toggle">toggle</a></td>
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td><a class="toggle">toggle</a></td>
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td><a class="toggle">toggle</a></td>
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td><a class="toggle">toggle</a></td>
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td><a class="toggle">toggle</a></td>
    <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data">
    <td></td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide toggle buttons in which their parent rows with class `header` don't precede a row with class `data`:

```
$('.header').each(function() {
  if(!$(this).next().hasClass('data')) {
    $(this).find('.toggle').hide();
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8em0ubo/)

Comment: I need all rows , just want to hide the toggle button not whole row

Comment: I now understand.  Updated.

Comment: very quick and elegant solution :) Thanks!